# Counter problem, infinite loop when post_per_page equals X

Tags: wp-query, loop

(updated)

I´m using this query to loop divs in to my front page slider. I use counters to split 4 posts into a slider, then open a new slider etc. Also a counter to set a class to every fourth post (to fix margin). This worked great until I wanted to use the 'post_per_page' argument. If I put it to -1 or something dividable by 4, I get an infinite loop that loops in all posts ad infinitum.

So. It´s pretty clear that my problem has to do with the counters. I´m not a coder myself and put this code together from different sources and with the help of the almighty internet.

This is what my full query looks like:

```
<ul id="slider1">
<?php 
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'fastighet',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby' => 'ASC'
             );
?>
<?php $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?> 
<?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<li class="4slide">     
<?php $count = 0; ?>    
<?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); $c++;
if( $c == 4) {
$style = 'thumbnail-fourth';
$c = 0;
}
else $style=''; ?> 

<div class="fastighet-thumbnail <?php echo($style) ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="fastighet-thumbnail-image">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'admin-list-thumb', array( 'alt' => ''.get_the_title().'', 'title' => ''.get_the_title().'' )); ?></a> 
    </div>

    <div class="fastighet-title">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>   
    </div>                                  
</div> <!-- end .fastighet-thumbnail -->

<?php $count++; if ( ( $count % 4 ) == 0 && $query->have_posts() ) { ?> 
<!-- if counter equals 4 then close the slide and open a new one -->
</li>
<li class="4slide">
<?php } endwhile; ?>
</li>
<?php endif; ?>     
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>  
</ul>
```

Can anybody see what´s wrong with this? How I could modify it to allow me to use 'posts_per_page' like I should be?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `$posts = get_posts($args)` line; not needed if you're calling a `WP_Query` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I still get an infinite loop though :/

Comment: Can you post how does the loop continue? do you have a `while ( $query->have_posts() )` next?

Comment: Can't comment above, but I think you're mixing `$c` and `$count` in your code.

Comment: Hm. I have two counters, a mish mash of code that I put together from different sources. One to put the classes on every forth div, and one to split them into different <li>:s. Maybe I could combine them somehow but I´m not good enough coder to do that. If anyone has any suggestions on how to optimize this code that would be great.

Comment: @englebip has a good point 'Can you post how does the loop continue?' - if the above code is only part of a template, please paste the full code into a http://pastebin.com/ and post the link to it here.

Comment: I think you should be able to use only one counter, you are keeping track of every fourth post in any case, so that `( $count % 4 ) == 0` should be true for every 4th post, as long as you start from 1 (i.e., the way you're doing it now, as you're incrementing the variable before checking its value). Also, I noticed that you increment `$c` before initializing it, which can lead to unexpected things. To try to debug this further, you can add some statements like `<?php echo $c. '<br/>'. $counter ?>` within the code to see how the loop is going.

Comment: Also, try removing the `&& $query->have_posts()` from the `if` statement near the end of the code; that will always be true as you are within the `while ($query->have_posts())` loop...

Answer (score 1):

This is old but i'll add the answer anyway for any future visitors

The problem is that `$query->have_posts()` also do a cleanup & reset all the posts when there are no posts left to loop. When this function is called inside the main while loop as the if condition, it reset the posts & then when it's called again in while condition, it starts the loop again from the beginning.

To solve this problem, use `$query->current_post + 1 != $query->post_count` inside your if condition

Comment: useful to know that about have_posts()